Error during inheritance from RazorPage<TModel>
I want to use localization in AspCore Razor Page.
But, I am encountering the following errors:
CS0108: 'Pages_Index.ViewData' hides inherited member 'RazorPage<IndexModel>.ViewData'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
CS0108: 'Pages_Index.Model' hides inherited member 'RazorPage<IndexModel>.Model'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
CS0103: The name 'PageContext' does not exist in the current context.
The type 'Pages_Index' is not a valid page. A page must inherit from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageBase'
My code is as follows:
public abstract class BaseViewPage<TModel> : RazorPage<TModel>  
{  
    [RazorInject]  
    public ILanguageService LanguageService { get; set; }  
    [RazorInject]  
    public ILocalizationService LocalizationService { get; set; }  
    public delegate HtmlString Localizer(string resourceKey, params object[] args);  
    private Localizer _localizer;  
    public Localizer Localize  
    {  
        get  
        {  
            //logic  
            
            return _localizer;  
        }  
    }  
}  

public abstract class CustomBaseViewPage : BaseViewPage<dynamic>  
{ }

And I use @inherits CustomBaseViewPage<TModel> in _ViewImports.cshtml.
The view code is:
@{  
    ViewData["Title"] = Localize("customer.page.create.title");  
}  
   
<div>  
     <h3>@Localize("customer.page.create.title")</h3>  
</div> 


using a generic page model is not supported in razor page ,you could check this issue :https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4865.   Is your goal to resolve errors or to implement  Localization?

First of all, if there isn't more about CustomBaseViewPage than just localization, this should not be necessary but instead you should inject the IStringLocalizer in every view you want to localize.
Nonetheless, you can also use your custom base class but you have to remove the @page directive in all pages as to not have multiple base classes which contain the same members. Also you have to take care of the routing, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-8.0
